# General Formula for Expected Number of Bernoulli Trials Needed for N successes in a Row, and the Standard Deviation of the Expected Number of Trials

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-probability, standard-deviation

Let “N” be the number of successes in a row that are happening entirely within the space of Bernoulli Trials. (Let “p” be p(success), and “q” be p(failure), where {q=1-p}). Let E(B) be the expected/mean/average number of trials needed for a streak of “N” successes in a row.

Generalize a solution of E(B) for any non-negative “N” and “p”. Generalize a solution for the variance and standard deviation of E(B). If some limits or approximations are needed, the important chunk of data is where p and N are appropriately sized with respect to each other, so E(B) does not go beyond around 10^8.

In practice, I want to get to the point where I can fill out E(B) and the STD of E(B), for any “p” and “N”:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzTWS.png)

The numbers are fillers for now, but that is what the finished product would look like.

(Note: There may be specific assumptions or exceptions I missed that would change the nature of the problem in an incorrect direction that I don’t want to include or venture towards.)

For instance, if p=0.5 we have a coinflip, and something like THHHHHT appears during our flipping, with 5 successful heads in a row, N would be 5. I'm looking for the expected number of coin flips (trials) to produce 5 successful heads in a row, I guess this would be E(B) or Expected number of Bernoulli Trials for N successes in a row, is what I was going for. And then the standard deviation of this expected number of Bernoulli Trials for N successes in a row. (And for any p and any N)

Comment: Your notation is odd...what is $B$?  Wouldn't it make more sense to write $E(N)$ since it is a function of $N$?  In any case, work recursively.  Try to write $E(N)$ in terms of $E(N-1)$.

Comment: @lulu $N$ is the required number of successive successes while $B$ seems to be the number of attempts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For instance, if p=0.5 we have a coinflip, and something like THHHHHT appears during our flipping, with 5 successful heads in a row, N would be 5. I'm looking for the expected number of coin flips (trials) to produce 5 successful heads in a row, I guess this would be E(B) or Expected number of Bernoulli Trials for N successes in a row, is what I was going for. And then the standard deviation of this expected number of Bernoulli Trials for N successes in a row. (And for any p and any N).

Comment: $E[B] = Np^N +\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (i+E[B])p^{i-1}q = \frac{Np^N +\sum\limits_{i=1}^N i p^{i-1}q}{1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^N p^{i-1}q}$ which can presumably be written in closed form.

Comment: Instead of trying to find the variance directly, I would aim for $E[B^2]$ first

Comment: It took me a while to make sure I asked the right question that I needed answered haha, I'm way out of my depth here and would need to learn a lot to correctly answer.  Wow, THANK YOU for E[B], the end goal is ultimately to find the standard deviation of this. So the next step is to find E[B^2], and from that you can find the variance, and then the standard deviation. Is the first step of E[B^2] straightforward? It looks messy to me at least, I'm unfamiliar with taking summations to powers.

Comment: It turns out $E[B]=\left(\dfrac1{p^N}-1\right)\dfrac1q$

Comment: With the more simple E[B], using wolfram alpha I have found $E[B^2]$ to be: $f(x) = (p^^-n) -1))^2/q^2$. With $variance=n*p*q$ , is E[B] just "np" or the "mean" in our case? So I can just multiply E[B] by q to find the variance, and then take the square root for the standard deviation? Or is this less straightforward?

Comment: Your $(p^{-n}-1)^2/q^2$ is not $E[B^2]$ but the rather smaller $(E[B])^2$

Comment: Ok I don't know how to do $E[B^2]$, I thought those were the same. I checked the simple formula for E[B] to wolfram alpha results and it seems to be off a little, probably just the calculators rounding. For example, if I input "Streak of 4 successes in 181 trials for p=0.3" Where N=4, E[B]=181, and p=0.3. It outputs an expected longest run of 4.00=N. But If I input N=4 and p=0.3 into the formula I get 175 for E[B] instead of 181. If I manage to find $E[B^2]$ how would I go about finding the variance and then the standard deviation?

Comment: Ahh, looks like your equation is exact and matches what I've found in this paper here (bottom of page 2, uses A instead of our E[B]). Wolfram alpha seems to be consistently off by about 1-5%!: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ginsparg/physics/INFO295/mh.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can find lot of works on the subject if you search on line about "consecutive k-out-of-n:F" systems. These are the systems which fail if k ( or more) consecutive components fail out of a total of n.

For instance you can read this paper,
["On success runs of a fixed length in Bernoulli sequences: Exact and
asymptotic results"- Frosso S. Makri, Zaharias M. Psillakis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81990604.pdf)
and the other works referenced there

Comment: I will research this, thank you for that clue!